# Why aspnet core environment are different from project configurations?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, build, configuration

I don't understand why [aspnet core environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) are different from default [visual studio configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2019).

The first has defaults like `Development`, `Staging`, `Production` and influence `Startup` and `appsettings.json`.

The latter has `Debug` and `Release` and determine the default build folder and the xml documentation.

Is it wrong to consider them separated in aspnet core solutions? Should i change the project configurations to match the aspnet core one?

Comment: Build configurations are for building, e.g. additional debug pdb file. ASP NET Core Environment is for runtime, so amount of debug in console for every request, etc

Comment: Still many incongruous scenario may arise when, for example, building the configuration related automatic xml documentation that is needed in the Development environment, because i want the open api documentation to be generated. Or worse when i expect some optimization on the Release configuration, but it's completely unrelated to Production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Configurations are used to tell MSBuild how to build a project - mostly just compile with debug on or off but it can be other things.

Asp.NET Core environments are used to change the behavior of how an application run *after* it is built and deployed (or debugged). You can use it to change the behavior in code by checking the environment value. Also, appsettings are added  based on environment. Appsettings.json is always loaded. If the environment is develop, appsettings.develop.json is loaded afterwards and the last settings loaded overwrite (or add too) the settings in appsettings.json. So usually you just use this environment variable to provide app settings per environment.

Comment: As I wrote on the question comment, some of the most common scenarios are equals if you merge those run time and build time switches: xml generation and optimizations are the two example I've used.  
If you only think at aspnet core, it looks more like something *from the past* rather than an actually useful thing to have by default.  
Basically, visual studio configurations can even be detrimental if you consider some tools like slowcheetah, a tool that create `appsettings.json` based on configurations and not environments.